# JQuery Bind on buttons in multiple table row

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of records which has about 300 rows on a jsp page . Each row has a delete button which makes an AJAX call and I want to bind all those buttons . I generally prefer to use jquery bind handler but in this case If i have a class for all those buttons will it make slower binding those button on page load ?

Should using OnClick='Somefunction(pass related row id)' be faster cause that will be rendered at page load instead of on .ready method  .

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a freelance website :)

Comment: @Dmitriy Naumov Not sure what does that mean ?!

Comment: this means that this site is for learning, not for ordering a free code.

Comment: @Dmitriy Naumov In my question there it's not mentioned that I want someone to write code . I am asking an advice on two approaches can implement something :) . And as far as I know stack overflow has no issue with that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each button a class and then use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live):

```
$('.mybuttonclass').live('click', function(event){
    // event.target is the clicked button
});
```

.live() works by [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling). jQuery attaches a listener to the document's event listener, and then fires on any events that match on the given selector.